# Remove duplicate values from an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

i have an array of objects like this:

```
arr = [
    {label: Alex, value: Ninja},
    {label: Bill, value: Op},
    {label: Cill, value: iopop}
]
```

This array is composed when my react component is rendered. The i user `Array.prototype.unshift` for adding a desired element in the top of my array.
So i write `arr.unshift({label: All, value: All})`. When my component first rendered my array is successfully created as i desire. But when i rerender it it shows me the array with the value `{label: All, value: All}` as duplicate. To be more specific it is shown something like this:

```
arr = [
    {label: All, value: All},
    {label: All, value: All},
    {label: Alex, value: Ninja},
    {label: Bill, value: Op},
    {label: Cill, value: iopop}
]
```

How can i fix this? I tried the methods described in a specific topic here but it didn't work

Comment: I've read this it is similar but not exactly duplicate. My case is different

Comment: Yeah, sure, they always are ... Please add the code you've tried.

Comment: What should that be strings or identifiers?

Comment: Yes, they are strings just wanted to show the case i'm facing

Comment: How is your case different?

Comment: Please add some code of your component ?

Comment: const euroTrade =
      cashAmounts.cash_amounts.find(avCash =>
        (avCash.currency === 'EUR'));
    let euroWithdrawAv;
    if (typeof euroTrade === 'undefined') {
      euroWithdrawAv = 0;
    } else {
      euroWithdrawAv = euroTrade.withDrawAmount;
    }
    cashTypes.unshift({ label: intl.formatMessage({ id: 'all.description' }), value: 'ALL' });
    let submitCashSearch;
    if (currentCashRadio === 'cashTransaction') {
      submitCashSearch = submitCashTransactionsSearch;
    } else {
      submitCashSearch = submitCashTransfersSearch;
    }

Comment: simply add `if (! arr.find(e => e.label === 'All' && e.value === 'All'))` before `unshift`

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` and `array#some`.

```js
const arr = [
    {label: 'All', value: 'All'},
    {label: 'All', value: 'All'},
    {label: 'Alex', value: 'Ninja'},
    {label: 'Bill', value: 'Op'},
    {label: 'Cill', value: 'iopop'}
]

var result = arr.reduce((unique, o) => {
    if(!unique.some(obj => obj.label === o.label && obj.value === o.value)) {
      unique.push(o);
    }
    return unique;
},[]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Want to give 1k upvote, but you have to manage in 1 :) . Well thanks for this perfect answer

Comment: how do yo do this if value (instead of a string value ) is equal to some array of strings ? and I need to remove the repeated strings in there and return arr ?

Answer (score 25):

**One liner solutions:**

Unique by `label` and `value`

```
arr.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(v2=>(v.label === v2.label && v.value===v2.value))===i)
```

Unique by all properties of the object:

```
arr.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(v2=>(JSON.stringify(v) === JSON.stringify(v2)))===i)
```

Comment: v,i,a == value, index, array

Comment: It doesn't work if the keys are not in the same order.

Answer (score 10):

This code worked for me,

```
const addresses = [...]; // Some array I got from async call

const uniqueAddresses = Array.from(new Set(addresses.map(a => a.id)))
 .map(id => {
   return addresses.find(a => a.id === id)
 })
```

Comment: This works for 1 property (id) but not 2 as the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
const things = {
  thing: [
    { id: '12345', name: 'First name' },
    { id: '12345', name: 'Second name' },
    { id: '34536', name: 'Third name' }, 
  ],
};

const RemoveDuplicates = (array, key) => {
  return array.reduce((arr, item) => {
    const removed = arr.filter(i => i[key] !== item[key]);
    return [...removed, item];
  }, []);
};

console.log(RemoveDuplicates(things.thing, 'id'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeDuplicates(array, key) {
   let lookup = {};
   array.forEach(element => {
     lookup[element[key]] = element
   });
   return Object.keys(lookup).map(key => lookup[key]);
};

removeDuplicates(array,'objectKey');
```

Answer (score -2):

ES1 compatible :

```js
const a = [
    {label: 'All', value: 'All'},
    {label: 'All', value: 'All'},
    {label: 'Alex', value: 'Ninja'},
    {label: 'Alex', value: 'Ninja'},
    {label: 'Alex', value: 'Ninja'}
]

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    for (let j = 0; j < a.length; ++j)
        if (i !== j && a[i].label === a[j].label && a[i].value === a[j].value)
            a.splice(j, 1);            
console.log(a);
```