# How to skip a duplicate object using a property value within reduce function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates

I have an array of objects like this:

```
// other properties of the object omitted for brevity
// this array can potentially contain upto 50 objects like this
var myArray = [{url: 'http://linkA'}, {url: 'http://linkB'}, {url: 'http://linkA'}]
```

I am trying to apply the reduce function to create a new object like this:

```
  var newArray = myArray.reduce(function(acc, current, index){
  var newObj = {};
  newObj['strata']  = 'kit';
  newObj['href'] = current['url'];
  acc.push(newObj);
  return acc;  
}, [])
```

But I do not want to include duplicate objects ('duplicate' tested using 'url' property of the object). How can i modify my reduce function to skip these kinds of objects and produce an

```
[{strata: kit, href: 'http://linkA'}, {strata: kit, href: 'http://linkB'}]
```

**Edit**: Sorry, i forgot to mention that this is legacy code. I cannot use features like 'Set' and 'some'

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate values from an array of objects in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439961/remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Note that when you're unconditionally pushing to a new array you've passed in as the accumulator in a `reduce` (as above), you're using the wrong tool; use `map` instead. (But if it's conditional, `map` wouldn't be appropriate and a simple loop is best.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the `url` exists in any of the objects in the accumulator first:

```js
var myArray = [{
  url: 'http://linkA'
}, {
  url: 'http://linkB'
}, {
  url: 'http://linkA'
}];

var newArray = myArray.reduce(function(acc, { url }, index) {
  if (acc.some(obj => obj.href === url)) {
    return acc;
  }
  acc.push({
    strata: 'kit',
    href: url
  });
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(newArray);
```

For `O(N)` complexity instead of `O(N^2)`, add each URL to an outer `Set` (whose lookup is `O(1)`, rather than `O(N)` for `Array.prototype.some`):

```js
var myArray = [{
  url: 'http://linkA'
}, {
  url: 'http://linkB'
}, {
  url: 'http://linkA'
}];

const urls = new Set();
var newArray = myArray.reduce(function(acc, { url }, index) {
  if (urls.has(url)) {
    return acc;
  }
  urls.add(url);
  acc.push({
    strata: 'kit',
    href: url
  });
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(newArray);
```

Or, in ES5, use an object instead of a Set:

```js
var myArray = [{
  url: 'http://linkA'
}, {
  url: 'http://linkB'
}, {
  url: 'http://linkA'
}];

var urls = {};
var newArray = myArray.reduce(function(acc, obj, index) {
  var url = obj.url;
  if (urls[url]) {
    return acc;
  }
  urls[url] = true;
  acc.push({
    strata: 'kit',
    href: url
  });
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Can I ask why use `Object.values(acc).some` rather than `acc.some`?

Comment: Oops, it's already an array, you're right. I'm used to the `.reduce`'s accumulator, when not a primitive, being an object

Comment: Can you please suggest how can i replace acc.some as this  is legacy code ?

Comment: @Adhyatmik Best to use Babel and [polyfills](https://polyfill.io/v3/) so that you can write in the latest and greatest version of the language - but if not, see edit, use an object instead of a Set, like in the bottom snippet

Comment: Should be: `if (urls[url]) { }` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check for duplicates using `some()` before `push()`

```js
var myArray = [{url: 'http://linkA'}, {url: 'http://linkB'}, {url: 'http://linkA'}]

var newArray = myArray.reduce(function(acc, current, index){
  var newObj = {};
  newObj['strata']  = 'kit';
  newObj['href'] = current['url'];
  if(!acc.some(x => x.href === current.url)) acc.push(newObj);
  return acc;  
}, [])

console.log(newArray)
```

A shorter version of code will be

```js
var myArray = [{url: 'http://linkA'}, {url: 'http://linkB'}, {url: 'http://linkA'}]

const res=  myArray.reduce((ac,a) => 
                  (!ac.some(x => x.href === a.url) && 
                  ac.push({strata:'kit',href:a.url}),
                  ac),
             []);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `some`:

```js
var myArray = [{url: 'http://linkA'}, {url: 'http://linkB'}, {url: 'http://linkA'}];

var newArray = myArray.reduce(function(acc, { url }, index) {
  if (Object.values(acc).some(({ href }) => href === url)) {
    return acc;
  }
  acc.push({
    strata: 'kit',
    href: url
  });
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get all the unique `url`s using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) first. Then create the objects using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

```js
const myArray = [{url: 'http://linkA'}, {url: 'http://linkB'}, {url: 'http://linkA'}],
      uniqueUrls = new Set(myArray.map(a => a.url)),
      strata = "kit",
      output = [...uniqueUrls].map(href => ({ strata, href }));

console.log(output)
```

If you can't use ES2015+ features, you can have an object as accumulator and each unique `url` as key. This way you'll get only one `url` in the accumulator. Then loop through the object and get the values of the merged object

```js
var myArray = [{url: 'http://linkA'}, {url: 'http://linkB'}, {url: 'http://linkA'}];

var merged = myArray.reduce(function(acc, current) {
  acc[current.url] = current;
  return acc;
}, {})

var output = [];

for(var key in merged) {
  output.push(merged[key])
}

console.log(output)
```

This is what the merged object will look like:

```
{
  "http://linkA": {
    "url": "http://linkA"
  },
  "http://linkB": {
    "url": "http://linkB"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a `Set` that accepts a mapped version of you array with only the urls in - The Set wil de-dupe your array and then you can create a new array from the Set with the `strata` property added to it.

```js
const myArray = [{url: 'http://linkA'}, {url: 'http://linkB'}, {url: 'http://linkA'}]
const s = new Set(myArray.map(({ url }) => url))

const newArray = [...s].map(url => ({
  url,
  strata: 'kit'
}))
console.log(newArray)
```

If you want your final Array of Objects to be more dynamic. Create a function that takes the parameter you want to de-dupe by and the params you want to insert into the finalized Object.

```js
const DE_DUPE_INSERT = (array, flag, insert) => {
  const s = new Set(array.map(item => item[flag]))
  return [...s].map(property => ({
    [flag]: property,
    ...insert
  }))
}
const ARR = [{url: 'http://linkA'}, {url: 'http://linkB'}, {url: 'http://linkA'}]
const de_duped = DE_DUPE_INSERT(ARR, 'url', {strata: 'kit', foo: 'bar'})

console.log(de_duped)
```

`< es6`

```js
var DE_DUPE_INSERT = function (array, flag, insert) {
  var de_duped = []
  array.forEach(function (item) {
    if (de_duped.indexOf(item[flag]) === -1) de_duped.push(item[flag])
  })
  
  return de_duped.map(function (property) { 
    var obj = {}
    obj[flag] = property
    Object.keys(insert).forEach(function (key) {
      obj[key] = insert[key]
    })
    return obj
  })
}
var ARR = [{url: 'http://linkA'}, {url: 'http://linkB'}, {url: 'http://linkA'}]
var de_duped = DE_DUPE_INSERT(ARR, 'url', {strata: 'kit', foo: 'bar'})

console.log(de_duped)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably

- Use a `Set` (or an object) to keep track of URLs I'd already seen, and
- Use an object initializer rather than three statements to create the new object, and
- Use a simple loop rather than `reduce`

But here's a version still using `reduce`:

```js
var myArray = [{url: 'http://linkA'}, {url: 'http://linkB'}, {url: 'http://linkA'}]
var known = new Set();
var newArray = myArray.reduce(function(acc, current, index){
  if (!known.has(current.url)) {
    acc.push({
      strata: 'kit',
      href: current.url
    });
    known.add(current.url);
  }
  return acc;  
}, [])
console.log(newArray);
```

Here's the to-my-mind simpler version using a loop:

```js
var myArray = [{url: 'http://linkA'}, {url: 'http://linkB'}, {url: 'http://linkA'}]
var known = new Set();
var newArray = [];
for (const current of myArray) {
  if (!known.has(current.url)) {
    newArray.push({
      strata: 'kit',
      href: current.url
    });
    known.add(current.url);
  }
}
console.log(newArray);
```

---

If you can't use ES2015+ features like `Set` and `for-of`, you can use an object to keep track of URLs and a simple `for` loop:

```js
var myArray = [{url: 'http://linkA'}, {url: 'http://linkB'}, {url: 'http://linkA'}]
var known = Object.create(null); // An object with no prototype
var newArray = [];
for (var index = 0; index < myArray.length; ++index) {
  var current = myArray[index];
  if (!known[current.url]) {
    newArray.push({
      strata: 'kit',
      href: current.url
    });
    known[current.url] = true;
  }
}
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention. This is legacy code  pre-ECMAScript 6. I dont think Set and some will work.

Comment: @Adhyatmik - Ah, then see the ES5 solution I added a moment ago at the end. :-)