# How to find if an object exist in an array [array is coming from localstorage]

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I created an empty array in `localStorage`

```js
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify([]))
```

and then fetching that empty array like this :

```js
let fetchedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));
```

After fetching the `Array` I want to append some objects in the same.

**Array of Objects**

```js
let objects = [
  {
     id: '37f60b13-bb3a-4919-beff-239207745343',
     body: '1',
  },
  {
     id: '26c5b0fa-b15f-4a50-9a56-5880727a8020',
     body: '2',
  },
  {
     id: '37f60b13-bb3a-4919-beff-239207745343',
     body: '1',
  },
];
```

The first and last object have same `id`

Right now what I am doing is, as I don't want to save or append duplicate objects **(by id key)** in `array/localstorage`:

```js
function saveItemsInLocalStorage(item) {
  let items;

  if (localStorage.getItem('items') === null) {
    items = [];
  } else {
    items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));
  }

  items.push({
    id: item.id,
    body: item.body,
  });

  localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
}

objects.forEach((object) => {
  fetchedItems.forEach((fetchedItem) => {
    if (fetchedItem.id !== object.id) {
      saveItemsInLocalStorage(object)
    }
  });
});
```

The above code is not working. I have also tried `reduce` method.

**Note** initially array is empty

Comment: `localStorage.setItem` does not automagically append arrays. It just writes the 2nd argument to the provided key (and in your current code, it's a single object, not the entire array.).  Also it takes a string as second argument, you probably want to to move your stringify.

Comment: Why are you stringifying the result of `setItem` and not using the value?

Comment: @Lars Sorry!! I messed up!! I modified the code take a look

Comment: @CristianTraìna Check the code now 

Comment: Please check out this post to see how to remove a duplicate objects from an array of objects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439961/remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: @Hani I have already search for these questions but haven't found the thing/answer.

Comment: From the question, at this line: `localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(todos));` - what is `todos`? Why is this being stored into localStorage? @Lars point merits a repeat here: simply performing `.setItem` will not append to existing array.

Comment: @jsN00b it is `items` typing mistake

Comment: Suppose the `id`s in `fetchedItems` are `1, 3, 4, 5` and those in `objects` are `2, 3, 4, 6`, the nested `forEach` loops will work like this. With `object.id` as `2` (outer `forEach`), every single `fetchedItem`'s `id` (ie, `1, 3, 4, 5`) will be checked. Since `2 !== 1`, `saveItemsInLocalStorage(2);` will execute (first time). Next, since `2 != 3`, `saveItemsInLocalStorage(2);` will execute (second time). So on & so forth.

Comment: @jsN00b it does work if the ids are different but as you can see I mentioned initially the array is empty so it doesn't matter what the first element goes in but if the `id` of second element is same as first. the second item should not get pushed in the `Array`.

Comment: Are you trying to continuously add items to the array? replace the items? Or do you want to keep the array to length = 1. I'm a little confused as to why you are setting the array in localstorage to an empty array each time. Also I don't see how you plan to access or append the array without parsing it back into a JavaScript object.

Comment: I want to keep adding items in the array! And also I am not setting the array empty!!

Answer (score 0):

Let us take an example and try understanding , how you can do it with your code :

```js
let obj = {name:"user",id:1};
let arr = [{name:"user",id:2},{name:"user",id:3}];
let present = false ;
arr.map(val=>{
   if(JSON.stringify( {...val})===JSON.stringify({...obj}) )
      present = true ;
})
if(present)console.log("The object is present")
else console.log("The object is not present");
```

Comment: I mentioned initially the array is empty and I can also do this without using `localStorage`. Btw thanks for the effort. 